# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 3 of the php page

Tags: php, html, sendmail

I'm trying to rectify the error for quiet some time now and I can't figure what's wrong with it. It is throwing out the parse error.

**Below is the HTML code: mail.php**

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
 
<table width="450px">
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top"">
 
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <textarea name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.xyz.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
</table>
 
</form>
```

**And here is the php code: send_form_email.php**

```
<?php
 
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
     
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
 
    $email_to = "xyz@gmail.com";
 
    $email_subject = "xyz";
 
     
 
     
 
    function died($error) {
 
        // your error code can go here
 
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
 
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
 
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
 
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
 
        die();
 
    }
 
     
 
    // validation expected data exists
 
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
 
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
 
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
 
    }
 
     
 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
 
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
 
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
 
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
 
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
 
     
 
    $error_message = "";
 
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
 
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
 
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
 
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
 
    died($error_message);
 
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
 
    function clean_string($string) {
 
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
 
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
 
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
 
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
     
 
     
 
// create email headers
 
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 
?>
 
 
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
 
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
 
 
<?php
 
}
 
?>
```

Can someone help me rectify this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I tested the code on my server and it works alright

Comment: Check if you don't have some strange characters before <?php. Your script seems to be right

Comment: @ceadreak: *before* <?php wouldn't produce a PHP Error

Comment: this won't work on localhost right? Only on a remote server?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try open it in Notepad++ and change the file's encoding.